# Convert from wchar_t to int

Tags: c++

I want to convert wchar_t array to int, I also search on Google but nothing resolve my problem ???

I mean, if wchar_t contain "54", i want convert into int is 54.

```
GetWindowText(hWndEdit, wMinute, 10);
iMinutes = (int)wMinute;
```

Not working right.

I'm happy if anyone can help me.

Comment: Typecasting is not magic. It doesn't do what you think it does. You are looking for `std::strtol()` et al. But read a beginner C++ tutorial first, this is way too basic. Oh, and that's not `wchar_t` but an **array** of `wchar_t`. Don't mislead readers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean want to convert array of wchar_t to int?

You can use wcstol function , or make yourself to understand:

Each elements in wchar_t array is 2 bytes. 
If wchar_t a[] = L"45", memory of a is:

```
34 00 35 00 00 00
```

34 is hexa value of ASCII "4", 35 is hexa value of ASCII "5"

if you convert directly like that:

```
int i = (int)a[0];
```

i will contain 52, why? Because, now i contain value 0x34 and it will be 52 in decimal.

OK, now, how to get i = 45 as you want?

This is my simple function to convert wchar_t to int like your require. This is only my idea:
First, you need to get value 4 from a[0] and 5 from a[1]. You can get by subtract 0x34 to 0x30, or (subtract 52 to 48), do like that with other elements.

After that, multiply each result with it's coefficient, example: 4 * 10, and 5 * 1 (see bellow to know how to get coefficient).

```
int miniPow(int a, int b)    // power with small number - just demo
{
    int r = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
        r *= a;
    }
    return r;
}
int WideToInt(wchar_t a[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int len = wcslen(a);
    int coefficient = 0;
    int RawNumber = 0;
    int Number = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < len; k++)
    {
        coefficient = miniPow(10, len - 1 - k);
        RawNumber = (int)a[k];
        Number = RawNumber - 48;
        i += coefficient * Number;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The function you want is `wcstol`. Like this

```
GetWindowText(hWndEdit, wMinute, 10);
iMinutes = wcstol(wMinute, 0, 10);
```

but I agree with H2C03 this is basic stuff. You really should learn how to find out this kind of information for yourself.

There's no error checking in this code, maybe you could test yourself and find out how to check if the conversion succeeded.